# Can an astronaut in free space turn his head without moving the rest of his body in opposite direction?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, angular-momentum, rotational-dynamics, conservation-laws, rotational-kinematics

Can an astronaut in free space turn his head without moving (turning) the rest of his body (and also not moving hands or legs) in opposite direction?